# Penalty for deleting one's own answer

Tags: discussion

I noticed one gets -25 points for deleting one's own answer. And if you undelete apparently you do not get those points back. Am I right?

Comment: See [Reputation decrease citing “User was removed”](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. You are wrong.

If you delete an answer the reputation change which occurred for that answer is annulled. That means the upvotes and downvotes on that (now deleted) answer no longer counts toward your reputation. (If you revive that question they start counting again.)

As a user you cannot delete an accepted answer.

There are no additional penalties for deleting an answer.

Comment: If you visit [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/29038/maesumi?tab=reputation), you will find that the -25 reputation you got today was due to a user being deleted. When a user's account is deleted the votes he cast toward your questions and answers are annulled.

Comment: I see. I guess the two events were close in timing and I got the wrong impression!

Answer (score 15):

You didn't lose points for deleting the answer.

The reputation loss is due to an account deletion. That is, someone who voted up your posts to the sum of 25 points were deleted and the votes are now gone.

Comment: I see. I guess the two events were close in timing and I got the wrong impression! Thanks.